# preg_replace pattern to remove pNUMBERxNUMBER

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to locate a pattern with `preg_replace()` and remove it...

I have a string, that contains this: `p130x130/` and these numbers vary, they can be higher, or lower ... what I need to do is locate that string, and remove it, whole thing.

I've been trying to use this:

```
 preg_replace('/p+[0-9]+x+[0-9]"/', '', $str);
```

but that doesnt work for some reason. Would any of you know the correct regexp?

Kind regards

Comment: You have a quote there; should probably just be `/p+[0-9]+x+[0-9]+/`

Answer (score 2):

You need to first remove the `+` quantifier after `p` then switch the `+` quantifier from after `x` and place it after your character class (e.g. `x[0-9]+`), also remove the quote `"` inside of your expression, which to me looks like a *typo* here. You can also use a different delimiter to avoid escaping the ending slash.

```
$str = preg_replace('~p[0-9]+x[0-9]+/~', '', $str);
```

If the ending slash is by mistake a *typo* as well, then this is what you're looking for.

```
$str = preg_replace('/p[0-9]+x[0-9]+/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex to match `p130x130/` is,

```
p[0-9]+x[0-9]+\/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = preg_replace("/p[0-9]+?x[0-9]+?\//is","",$str);
```

As mentioned by the comment I have to explain the code as I'm a teacher now.

I've used "/" as a delimiter, but you can use different characters to avoid slashing.
The part that says `[0-9]+` is saying to match any character between `0` and `9` at least once, but more if possible. If I had put `[0-9]*?` then it would have matched an empty space too (as `*` means to match 0 or more, not 1 or more like `+`) which is probably not what you wanted anyway.

I've put the `?` at the end to make it non-greedy, just a habit of mine but I don't think it's needed. (I used ereg a lot previously).

Anyway, it's going to find `0-9` until it hits an `x`, and then it does another match for more numbers until it hits a single forward slash. I've backslashed that slash because my delimiter is a slash also and I didn't want it to end there.

Comment: It might be right, but it was flagged, so I'd add some explanation so you don't get it deleted.

Comment: Tried my best Aaron. Sorry for making someone edit it all to make it look nice (and also thanks Ed) :)